# Auto Login for Gmail account via a redirected URL without having gmail login credentials

Tags: php, redirect, gmail, autologin

My task is to make any user **login into Gmail without knowing the login credentials.**

I have made a page called **test.php** where i will **pass the username & password** for gmail account and also **redirect it to Gmail login URL**.

After researching, i got this **URL**..

https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http://mail.google.com/gmail&service=mail&Email=disha26th@gmail.com&Passwd=PASSWORD&null=Sign+in

Here my email gets auto-populated in the **Gmail login form** but **not pasword**.

Can anyone...resolve it.. or tell me some other way to achieve it.. Thanks..

Comment: Did you just post a password on the internet? Hopefully it was trash, but if you did let it slip, go change immediately.

Comment: Oh no... dat is a wrong password. Thanx for the concern..

Comment: This is not possible due to the way Google protects their authentication process. In addition, I believe it is against their terms of service.

Comment: @Brad are u sure it is not possible .. ??

Comment: If I wasn't sure, I wouldn't have told you.

Comment: do you use CURL for access google login. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$params = "accountType=GOOGLE&Email=".$email."&Passwd=".$password."&service=cp&source=moneymagpie"; [$email = Your from email, $password = Your form password]

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Try out with this code.

Comment: Can u pls POST the full code as it is not working.. and gives me error **Call to undefined function curl_init() on line no. XX**

Comment: 1) Close WAMP (if running)
2) Navigate to WAMP\bin\php\(your version of php)\
3) edit php.ini
4) Search for curl, uncomment extension=php_curl.dll
5) Save php.ini
6) Restart WAMP

Comment: run phpinfo(); function and search "curl".If not found then curl is not installed in your wamp server.